# Unnecessary requests coming on google cloud end points

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have deployed API endpoint using google cloud end point by following below tutorial:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-kubernetes-engine

But along with my actual endpoint, hundreds of requests are coming on different end points which I haven't configured in open API specification.

I am not getting any idea who is sending these requests to my api end point.
Am I missing something or is it a DDoS on my end point?

[image: API counts]

[image: logs of api end points]

Comment: This looks like typical `script kiddies` looking for vulnerable endpoints. If you have public HTTP endpoints, you will see this 24x7 every day.

Comment: Thanks John. My concern is this script kiddies is consuming 99% of my API quota. Will the problem resolve if I am setting up SSL for end point?

Comment: Setting up SSL will have no impact. There is nothing that you can do if your endpoints are public. Anyone can call them.